# Myhill-Nerode equivalence under a function

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Consider two finite languages, $L_A$ and $L_B$, potentially over different alphabets. Now since these languages are finite, there exist minimal acyclic deterministic finite-state automata to decide them. We are given that $L_A$ is bigger than $L_B$: $|L_A| > |L_B|$.

We are given a function $f$ which maps elements of $L_A$ to $L_B$: $\ f{:}L_A \rightarrow L_B$. We also have the constraint that acceptance is preserved under $f$: $\ \ x \in L_A$ iff $f(x) \in L_B$, modeled below by formula $\eqref{eq1}$.

Here's the question: if two strings $u$ and $v$ map to the same Myhill-Nerode equivalence class in $B$ under $f$ [modeled by formula $\eqref{eq2}$], do they map to the same equivalence class in $A$ [modeled by formula $\eqref{eq3}$]? That is, if we are given formulas $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$, can we conclude formula $\eqref{eq3}$?

$\forall x((x \in L_A) \leftrightarrow (f(x) \in L_B)) \tag{1} \label{eq1}$

$\forall z((f(uz) \in L_B) \leftrightarrow (f(vz) \in L_B)) \tag{2}  \label{eq2}$

$\forall z((uz \in L_A) \leftrightarrow (vz \in L_A)) \tag{3}  \label{eq3}$

Is there some existing result which subsumes what I'm trying to do here? It feels very similar to the [closure property under homomorphisms](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/fa2010/lectures/notes09-10.pdf). Or do we need to prove the result, for instance by two applications of formula $\eqref{eq1}$ to formula $\eqref{eq2}$ to yield theorem $\eqref{eq3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  [(1)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152827/myhill-nerode-equivalence-under-a-function#mjx-eqn-eq1) and [(2)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152827/myhill-nerode-equivalence-under-a-function#mjx-eqn-eq2) imply formula [(3)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152827/myhill-nerode-equivalence-under-a-function#mjx-eqn-eq3).

$\forall z$, $(uz \in L_A) \leftrightarrow (f(uz)\in L_B) \leftrightarrow (f(vz)\in L_B) \leftrightarrow (vz\in L_A)$.

Comment: It does not matter whether $L_A$ is finite and whether $L_B$ is finite. It does not matter whether $L_A$ is regular and whether $L_B$ is regular.